# add and remove product options in shopping cart

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, shopping-cart, cart

Humm..After trying so many shopping cart codes by customizing according to my requirements I still not got proper solution.:(

I have two tables products and productoptions in which i stored the color or size of product. One product can have different sizes and colors.

Now the problem is I am unable and frustrated to integrate/ customize the code according to above scenario. There are issues coming like I can't add one product with two different colors and remove one of them. While removing one of them, the cart becomes empty.

Can anyone please suggest me how should I achieve the shopping cart with above scenario? Any online reference examples or any relevant source demo will be helpful if someone had done this type before.

Friends please suggest. I doing this first time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have tried customizing these [LInk1](http://www.sanwebe.com/2015/03/ajax-shopping-cart-with-php-and-jquery) , [LInk2](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/06/creating-simple-shopping-cart-with-php/comment-page-1), [Link3](http://phppot.com/php/simple-php-shopping-cart/) etc. But nothing works properly or i don't know properly the right method of doing that.:(

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler than you think.

Use sessions.

So let's say these two products have an id of 1.

Let's also admit there's no stock check, and you have an unlimited amount of products.

Whenever you add a product to your cart, add to $_SESSION['products'][]['item'] id of 1. You can also add ['color'] and such. But this will be one item.

At this point, you'll have to loop over your $_SESSION array to display your products.

Do it, and mark the div containing your product with the index that corresponds to its slot in your $_SESSION created earlier, with an input hidden for example.

Now whenever you'll click on delete, you should send the index marked in the div to the code deleting the product from cart.
With the index, delete the corresponding array in $_SESSION['products'].

Once this is done, only the remaining products will be displayed and counted in the cart.

This is only one method among many. Using AJAX is advised for a better user experience, it'll be more fluid.

But if you're new to all this, starting with simple PHP is advised.

Comment: hey thanks for reply.:) I would like to use ajax. actually the php in that is becoming complex for me. if id 1 with different color added to cart and if one of them click for remove then both gets removed. so I am trying to add product with its id/code and color. so that unique product will be deleted. But i am unable to modify.

Comment: please check this [demo](http://www.sanwebe.com/assets/ajax-shopping-cart-demo/). this is what I wanted to look like. but its functionality is not working properly as i wanted. e.g. if we add `Cool T-shirt` with different color then same product is updated which is not right.  `Cool T-shirt | Red` and  `Cool T-shirt | Blue` should be added to cart and count should be `2`. and if we remove   `Cool T-shirt | Red` that only must be removed. not both of them.